# How to replace a existing tab in Jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane with 5 tabs. I have a JPanel added to each tab say 5 JPanel's, which has several components on each tab. If i want to update a tab content dynamically depending on a flag variable say to replace the content on tab 4, i need to replace existing panel with new Jpanel, how do i achieve this dynamic update on a particular tab?

Answer (score 2):

There are more possibilities to achieve that.

The first possibility is to replace the content of the pane. Assuming you have added the pane you want to update as follows:

```
 this.content = new JPanel();
 this.content.add(new JLabel("Content1"));
 myPane.addTab("Tab1", this.content);
```

Then you can change the content of the tab:

```
 this.content.removeAll();
 this.content.add(new JLabel("Content2"));
 this.content.revalidate();
 this.content.repaint();
```

The second possibility is to completely remove the tab and afterwards add a new one with the new content.

```
 myPane.removeTabAt(index);
 myPane.addTab("New Tab", newContent);
```

Generally I would prefer the first possibility.

Comment: `Generally I would prefer the first possibility` - except that code won't work. When you add/remove components from a visible GUI you need to revalidate() and repaint() the panel to make sure the layout manager is invoked and then the components are repainted.

Answer (score 1):

I fought this silly problem for a day before I was able to tell apart JTabbedPane's getComponentAt and getTabComponentAt methods. FYI, the first gets the content of the tab and the latter the tab's title bar component -.-
I used something like this:

```
//create new content for tab
JPanel tabPanel = generateTab();
//assign new content to tab
tabbedPane.setComponentAt(index, tabPanel);
```